# Number of elements in smallest subset of $X$

Tags: combinatorics

> Let $\displaystyle X=\{n\in\mathbb{N}:1\leq n\leq 50\}$.
> If $\displaystyle A=\{n\in\mathbb{X}: n\ \text{is multiple of} \ 2\}$ and
> $\displaystyle B=\{n\in\mathbb{X}: n\ \text{is multiple of} \ 7\}$.
> Then number of elements in smallest subset of $X$ containing both $A$ and $B$ is

My try : Here we have to find $A\cap B$

Which is $\displaystyle A\cap B =\{14,28,42\}$

So number of element in smallest subset of $X$ Containing both $A$ and $B$ is $3$

But answer given as $29$ (Seems that it has take $A\cup B$)

I did not understand Why my answer is wrong and as per as language of question it should be $A\cap  B$

Please have a look on that , Thanks

Comment: I don't understand.  $|A|=25$ so obviously any set that contains $A$ has at least $25$ elements.

Comment: I think you are misreading.  They are asking for the union, not the intersection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the question asks for smallest subset $S\subseteq X$ that "contains" $A$ and $B$, what it is asking for is $A\subseteq S$ and $B\subseteq S$.

Clearly then $S\neq A\cap B$, since what we want is $A\subseteq A\cap B$ and $B\subseteq A\cap B$, which is true if and only if $A = B$. But we know by the definitions of $A$ and $B$ that the two sets are not equal.

What you are looking for is $A\cup B$, this is the set that contains both $A$ and $B$. It is also the smallest such set, both of these statements you can prove fairly directly from the definition.